# Get permanently the output from a shell command running in C++

Tags: c++, popen

I want to get the output from a shell command (my_program). Here is a example taken from [this](http://www.minoraddition.com/2011/03/23/popen-execute-shell-command-from-cc/) site:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   FILE *in;
   char buff[512];

   if(!(in = popen("my_program", "r"))){
      return 1;
   }

   while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
      cout << buff;
   }
   pclose(in);

   return 0;
}
```

**The problem:**

I want to run my program permanently and get the output while the program is still running, NOT only get the output from the program once.

Any idea?

Comment: 1) open three pipes, 2) fork off, 3) `dup2` and jiggle file descriptors, 4) `exec` in the child.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - what do you mean by 'permanently'?  Why not make 'my_program' run 'permanently'?

Comment: @KerrekSB, i already thought using fork/threads. But would like to know if there is another optional. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Wait, do you just need to read the standard output, or do you need control over all three streams?

Comment: @trojanfoe, well, permanently means run while another program in running. With the code above "my_program" only runs once. But i want that my program runs until i say so. In other words, it's like running in background.

Comment: @KerrekSB, well, with the output i want to run a personal and simply function (search for a pattern).

Comment: You didn't answer my question, but perhaps `popen` will do fine for what you have, and you just need a loop that keeps checking if there's more data available for reading.

Comment: @KerrekSB, sorry that i didnt answer your question :(. In your last comment, how can i know if there is more data available?

Comment: @GabrielMuñumel: The usual blocking `read` or non-blocking `select` socket gymnastics should do, non?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear but I suspect that the problem is buffer and the answer flushing: The way I understand is the program `my_program` produced outputs occassionally and the program you show should kick into action when `my_program` prints something. Further I suspect that this program doesn't produce a lot of output in total, e.g. less than 4k.

The problem is that most implementations buffer  standard output differently depending of whether this is directed to a "console" or something else: when writing to the console output tends to be line-buffer while other destinations buffer substantially bigger buffers. However, the buffer can be explicitly flushed, reducing the performance of the output substantially. Of course, in the scenario above you'd be more interest in timely outputs rather than output performance.

A simple approach to flush an output buffer in C++ us to use `out << std::flush`. If you quickly want to verify that this the problem you can set up the stream to flush after every output operation using `out << std::unitbuf`. There are a number of other approaches to automatically flush but these are a bit more involved.